# Wurtz reaction on acidic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, redox

Why can Na not be used for the Wurtz reaction of compounds having an acidic group like alcohol or carboxylic acid?

Comment: Well why do you think? What happens when you react an acid with sodium?

Comment: But Wurtz reaction happens in solvents like ether right? Is Na basic there too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With alkanols, sodium will form alkoxides (and hydrogen gas).
$$\ce{2CH3OH + 2Na -> 2 CH3ONa +H2 ^}$$
With alkanoic acids, sodium will form alkanoates (and hydrogen gas).
$$\ce{2CH3COOH + 2Na -> 2 CH3COONa +H2 ^}$$

If your starting material contains both an $\ce{OH}$ group and a bromo substituent, the alkoxide formed upon the reaction with sodium may attack the carbon bearing the $\ce{Br}$ atom in a substitution reaction to yield a cyclic ether.